# PEP proxy config file for integration of IDM GE, PEP proxy and Cosmos big data

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

I have a question regarding PEP proxy file.
My keystone service is running on 192.168.4.33:5000.
My horizon service is running on  192.168.4.33:443.

My WebHDFS service is running on 192.168.4.180:50070
and i intend to run PEP Proxy on 192.168.4.180:80

But what i don't get is what should i put in place of config.account_host?
Inside mysql database for keyrock manager there is "idm" user with "idm" password and every request i make via curl on Identity manager works.

But with this config:

```
config.account_host = 'https://192.168.4.33:443';
config.keystone_host = '192.168.4.33';
config.keystone_port = 5000;
config.app_host = '192.168.4.180';
config.app_port = '50070';
config.username = 'idm';
config.password = 'idm';
```

when i start pep-proxy with:

```
sudo node server.js
```

i get next error:

```
Starting PEP proxy in port 80. Keystone authentication ...
Error in keystone communication {"error": {"message": "The request you     
have made requires authentication.", "code": 401, "title":   
"Unauthorized"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I wouldn't type the port at your `config.account_host`, as it is not required there, but this doesn't interfere the operation.

My guessing is that you are using your own [KeyRock FIWARE Identity Manager](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm) with the default provision of roles.

If you check the code, PEP Proxy sends a [Domain Scoped request](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy/blob/master/lib/idm.js#L37) against KeyRock, as stands in the [Keystone v3 API](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html#domain-scoped).

So the thing is, the `idm` user you are using to authenticate PEP, probably doesn't have any domain roles. The workaround to check it would be:

1. Try the `Domain Scoped` request:

   ```
   curl -i \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '
   { "auth": {
       "identity": {
         "methods": ["password"],
         "password": {
           "user": {
             "name": "idm",
             "domain": { "id": "default" },
             "password": "idm" 
           }
         }
       },
       "scope": {
         "domain": {
           "id": "default" 
         }
       }
     }
   }' \
     http://192.168.4.33:5000/v3/auth/tokens ; echo
   ```

If you get a `401` code, you are not authorized to make `Domain Scoped` requests.

2. Check if the user has any role in this domain. For this you will need to get an Auth token using the [Default Scope](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html#default-scope) request:

   ```
     curl -i   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '
   { "auth": {
       "identity": {
         "methods": ["password"],
         "password": {
           "user": {
             "name": "idm",
             "domain": { "id": "default" },
             "password": "idm" 
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }'   http://192.168.4.33:5000/v3/auth/tokens ; echo
   ```

This will return a `X-Subject-Token` that you will need for the workaround.

3. With that token, we will send a request to the `default` domain using the user we selected before, `idm`, to check if we have assigned any roles there:

   ```
   curl -i \
       -H "X-Auth-Token:<retrieved_token>" \
       -H "Content-type: application/json" \
   http://192.168.4.33:5000/v3/domains/default/users/idm/roles
   ```

And probably, this request will give you a response like:

`{"links": {"self": "http://192.168.4.33:5000/v3/domains/default/users/idm/roles", "previous": null, "next": null}, "roles": []}`

4. In that case, you will need to create a role for that user. To create it, you will need to assing a `role` to the user `idm` in the `default` domain. For that, you will need to retrieve the `role id` of the `role` you want to assign. You can do this by sending the following request:

   ```
   curl -i \
       -H "X-Auth-Token:<retrieved_token>" \
       -H "Content-type: application/json" \
   http://192.168.4.33:5000/v3/roles
   ```

It will return a JSON with all the available `roles` and its `ids`.

5. Assign a `role` to the user `idm` in the `default` domain. There are 6 available: member, owner, trial, basic, community and admin. As `idm` is the main administrator, I would chose the `admin id`. So finally, with the `admin id`, we assign the role by doing:

   ```
   curl -s -X PUT \
       -H "X-Auth-Token:<retrieved_token>" \
       -H "Content-type: application/json" \
   http://192.168.4.33:5000/v3/domains/default/users/idm/roles/<role_id>
   ```

Now you can try again Step 1, and if everything works, you should be able to start the PEP proxy:

```
sudo node server.js
```

Let me know how it goes!